# download files from server and compress it in zip format

Tags: jsf, primefaces

im trying to implement a download all functionality, my requirement is file should be compressed in .zip, heres the UI

```
<p:toolbar>
    <f:facet name="right">
         <p:commandButton value="Download all photos" ajax="false" actionListener="#{ManageActivities.getAllParticipantPhoto}" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);" icon="ui-icon-image">
            <p:fileDownload value="#{ManageActivities.file}" /> 
      </p:commandButton>
  </f:facet></p:toolbar>
```

and here is the managedbean code

```
private StreamedContent file;

public void getAllParticipantPhoto() {   
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(zipBytes());
    InputStream stream = bis;
    file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "zip", "photos.zip");
```

}

```
private byte[] zipBytes () {   
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);

    try{
        for(Participants p : partcpnts){
            if(p.getPhoto() != null){
                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(p.getFirstName()+".jpg");
                zos.putNextEntry(entry);
                zos.write(p.getPhoto());
               }                
            }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

i can download file as ZIP successfully but i am unable to extract it, windows is prompting the'cannot open file as archive' error

Comment: @Javier i've added closing the ZipOutputStream , still unable to extract files

Comment: Can you post the HTTP response headers when you download the ZIP file? Does it fail in all browsers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

changing

```
file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "zip", "photos.zip");
```

to

```
file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/zip", "photos.zip",  Charsets.UTF_8.name());
```

fixed it

Comment: My problem is resolved by this solution. Thank you :)

Comment: I had to do zos.closeEntry(); zos.finish(); after finishing the for-loop in order to close the stream. Then it worked in Windows (even without setting the charset). 7zip is very useful, it will show you that the last zipped file is actually empty.